# A simple question about conditional expectation

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

If I got

$$E\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)\right)$$

Why is it equal to

$$E\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)\right)=E\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)\mid\min\left(X,Y\right)=X\right)P\left(X\le Y\right)+E\left(\min\left(X,Y\right)\mid\min\left(X,Y\right)=Y\right)P\left(X>Y\right)$$

Comment: I don't understand what RHS stands for. Are you using $:$ for conditional expectation ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I do

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the event $)X \leq Y$ and $B=(X>Y)$. Then  $E(X\wedge Y)=E((X\wedge Y) I_A)+E((X\wedge Y) I_B)=E(X\wedge Y : A) P(A)+E(X\wedge Y : B) P(B)$.

Note: $E(X:A)$ is defined as $\frac 1 {P(A)} EXI_A$.

Comment: Why do you use a conjunction and not an alternative? Also, what is I_A and I_B (how is it called?)

Comment: $I_A$ is the indicator function or characteristic function of $A$. It has the value $1$ for points of $A$ and $0$ for points not in $A$.  $X\wedge Y$ is just a notation for $\min (X,Y)$.